# Using a JQuery sticky/following sidebar but box header image doesn't move with the text?

Tags: jquery, html, css, sidebar, sticky

In advance, thanks.

I have been using sticky sidebar code from [HERE](http://andrewhenderson.me/tutorial/jquery-sticky-content) and I was customising the style by adding a image header to the box but when in place it does not follow with the text you can see for yourself here: [thomas-dixon.com/joomla](http://thomas-dixon.com/joomla).

Heres the code I'm using:

```
[view-source:http://thomas-dixon.com/joomla/][3]
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/hjeBP/

Replace your **jQuery** code with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ // document ready
  
  if (!!$('#sidebar-left-content').length) { // make sure "#sidebar-left-content" element exists
  
  var el = $('#sidebar-left-wrap');
  var stickyTop = $('#sidebar-left-content').offset().top; // returns number
  var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top; // returns number
  var stickyHeight = $('#sidebar-left-content').height();
  var limit = footerTop - stickyHeight - 20;
  
  $(window).scroll(function(){ // scroll event
                   
                   var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // returns number
                   
                   if (stickyTop < windowTop){
                   el.css({ position: 'fixed', top: 0 });
                   }
                   else {
                   el.css('position','static');
                   }
                   
                   if (limit < windowTop) {
                   var diff = limit - windowTop;
                   el.css({top: diff});
                   }
                   
                   });
  
  }
  });</script>
```

Working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/hjeBP/